# Compare time difference of two dates

Tags: python, file, time, compare

I hope the community can support me
following situation

I have two files that I have already checked for existence, now I have already read the modification date and saved it in two variables. Now I want to allow a maximum difference of 10 min between the two files.

Here is my unfinished code:

```
       if os.path.isfile(savefile + 'pickle_raw.txt'):
            modTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getmtime(savefile + 'pickle_raw.txt')
            modificationTime0 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(modTimesinceEpoc))
            print("Last Modified on:", modificationTime0, "pickle_raw.txt")
        else:
            print("Logfile Error")
            sys.exit()


        if os.path.isfile(savefile + 'pickle_RawIfExist.txt'):
            modTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getmtime(savefile + 'pickle_RawIfExist.txt')
            modificationTime1 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(modTimesinceEpoc))
            print("Last Modified on:", modificationTime1, "pickle_RawIfExist.txt")
        else:
            src = (savefile + 'pickle_raw.txt')
            des = (savefile + 'pickle_RawIfExist.txt')
            shutil.copy(src, des)
            print("pickle_raw.txt is copy to pickle_RawIfExist.txt")
            print("Exit the Programm")
            sys.exit()
```

Thank you very much for your help.

I have tried to compare the date.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've saved these times under `modTimesinceEpoc0` and `modTimesinceEpoc1`.

You can compare using numbers, but this is not very understandable and easy to work with, so it's usually easier to use the built in `datetime` library that handles dates and times:

```py
import datetime
modTime0 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modTimesinceEpoc0)
modTime1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modTimesinceEpoc1)
modDifference = abs(modTime0 - modTime1)
if modDifference > datetime.timedelta(minutes=10):
    print("No!")
    sys.exit()
print("Yay")
```

First we convert the numbers to `datetime.datetime` which is a class that represents dates.

Then we subtract them to get `datetime.timedelta` which is a class that represents time differences.

We use `abs` to get the positive difference, because we don't know which date was bigger.

Finally we compare it to another `timedelta` instance we create ourselves, which is a time difference of 10 minutes. The `timedelta` class supports less-than and greater-than comparisons for such cases.

If you just want to use simple numbers (which I would advise against), you can use `if abs(modTimesinceEpoc0 - modTimesinceEpoc1) > 10*60`, where `10*60` is the amount of seconds in 10 minutes.